# How to use a php variable as a value in a select tag?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project that allows the user to edit an existing form, however I am having trouble displaying the current status of the form. this was my idea to solve this problem:

I first fetched the existing data and stored the previously set status of the form like this:

```
<?php $existingStatus = $formValues['status']; ?>
```

I can echo this existingStatus variable, and it returns the previously set status, so I know that existingStatus is holding the status that the form currently is.

however this variable is not working when I try and put it as an option in the dropdown list. this was my idea of how it would work:

```
<select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
     **<option value="<?php $existingStatus; ?>">CURRENT STATUS: <?php echo $existingStatus ?></option>**
     <option value="active">Active</option>
     <option value="void">Void</option>
     <option value="paid">Paid</option>
     <option value="not paid">Not Paid</option>
```

the options label does change dependent on the status of the form, however if a user were to not change the form from this option displaying the current status, upon submission the status would be blank.

I'm sorry if I have done a rough job of explaining this problem, and I am unable to share photos of the problem either, but my overall question is how can I use a php variable as a value for an option tag?

Comment: You don't use it as a value. You already have all values.

Comment: what I understood is you want to show current status selected by-default, for that do this:

`<select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
 <option value="active" <?php echo $formValues['status'] == 'active' ? 'selected':'';?>>Active</option>
 <option value="void" <?php echo $formValues['status'] == 'void' ? 'selected':'';?>>Void</option>
 <option value="paid" <?php echo $formValues['status'] == 'paid' ? 'selected':'';?>>Paid</option>
 <option value="not paid" <?php echo $formValues['status'] == 'not paid' ? 'selected':'';?>>Not Paid</option>
</select>`